# Iterate consecutive elements in a list in Python such that the last element combines with first

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to iterate consecutive elements in the list such that, when it comes to last element i'e **8** it pairs with the first element **1**.

The final output I want is:

```
[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[8,1]
```

I tried using this way:

```
for first,second in zip(L, L[1:]):
    print([first,second])
```

But I am getting only this result:

```
[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8]
```

How do I make a pair of last element with first? I have heard about the negative indexing property of a list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply extend the second list in `zip()` with a list with only the first item, something like:

```
for first, second in zip(L, L[1:] + L[0:1]):  # or simply zip(L, L[1:] + L[:1])
    print([first, second])
```

Comment: `L[0:1] == L[0] == L[:1]`

Comment: `L[0:1] == L[0]  # returns False`, L[0] gives `1`, L[0:1] gives `[1]` (a list)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle the lists (in combination with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip the first element):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
rest_L_cycled = islice(cycle(L), 1, None)
items = zip(L, rest_L_cycled)
print(list(items))
```

This is easily extensible. Note that it relies on the fact that `zip` halts on the shorter list (the second argument is an infinite cycle). It also does everything lazily and does not create any intermediate list (well, except for the `print`ed list) :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can just append the front element(s) to the back.

```
for first,second in zip(L, L[1:] + L[:1]):
    print([first,second])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also iterate through the indexes of `L`, and for the index of the second item of the output tuples, simply use the remainder of the length of `L`:

```
[(L[i], L[(i + 1) % len(L)]) for i in range(len(L))]
```

Comment: @blshing I think it the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply concatenate the list resulting from zip(L, L[1:]) with the pair formed by the last element L[-1] and first one L[0] and iterate over the result

```
for first,second in zip(L, L[1:]) + [(L[-1],L[0])]:
    print ([first,second])
```

It gives the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a one-liner, but:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> z = list(zip(L[:-1], L[1:]))
>>> z.append((L[-1], L[0]))
>>> z
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a version (over-)using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for a, b in zip(L, islice(cycle(L), 1, None)):
    print(a, b)
```

The idea is to `cycle` over the second argument - that way `zip` runs until `L` itself is exhausted. This does not create any new lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(L)):
   first = L[i]
   second = L[(i+1) % len(L)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `itertools.zip_longest` with a `fillvalue` of the first item.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list(map(tuple, zip_longest(L, L[1:], fillvalue=L[0]))
```